# Schedule Update One in ccTouchesMoved/Pause Timer/Resume Timer - Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm just trying to schedule an update method once in ccTouchesMoved, but when I add this

```
if (isRotating == YES)
        {
            gTimer = 20;
            [self schedule:@selector(g:) interval:1];
        }
```

in to ccTouchesMove it calls it every time the touch is moved. Is there a way to keep it in ccTouchesMoved and have it called just once?

`isRotating` is set to YES in `ccTouchesMoved`.

Code:

```
- (void)g:(ccTime)delta
{
    gTimer--;

    if (gTimer == 0 && isRotating == YES)
    {
        [self unschedule:@selector(g:)];
    }
}
```

All I want to do is rotate a sprite for a fixed interval then remove it when the timer is 0, but I only want to remove it if the touch is currently rotating the sprite.

Here is where pausing/resuming the timer comes in. If the player starts rotating the sprite then lifts their finger, the timer should pause and when they touch/rotate the sprite again the timer should resume.

If my explaining isn't clear please feel free to ask me to elaborate.

Timer methods:

In .h

```
ccTimer gTimer;
```

In .m

```
- (void)g:(ccTime)delta
{
    gTimer--;

    if (gTimer == 0 && isRotating == YES)
    {
        [self unschedule:@selector(g:)];
    }
}
```

Also, I set the timer with

```
if (isRotating == YES)
        {
            gTimer = 20;
            [self schedule:@selector(g:) interval:1];
        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pause the timer I just used

```
[self unschedule:@selector(g:)];
```

then to resume it I used

```
[self schedule:@selector(g:)];
```

Also, for scheduling update in ccTouchesMoved I just checked to see if the finger and stopped moving without being lifted.

Answer (score 0):

Put a BOOL touched in your class.. and float myTimer as well..

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    touched = YES;
}
-(void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    isRotating = YES;

    if(touched && isRotating)
    {
       gTimer = 20;
           [self schedule:@selector(g:) interval:0.03];
    }   
  }
-(void)ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    touched = NO;
    [self unschedule:@selector(g:)];
}


- (void)g:(ccTime)delta
{
    myTimer +=delta;

    if (myTimer >= gTimer && isRotating == YES)
    {
        [self unschedule:@selector(g:)];
    }
}
```